# Is it wrong to call a class a FooFactory if it doesn't *always* create Foo objects?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, naming-conventions, factory, service-locator

Is it wrong to call a class a FooFactory if it doesn't *always* create Foo objects? For example if I have the following interface:

```
public interface IFooFactory
{
    Foo Create();
}
```

and implement it as follows:

```
public class FooFactory : IFooFactory
{
    public IFoo Create()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IFoo>();
    }
}
```

then this class *might* create a Foo depending upon how my IoC container is configured. If the 'XxxFacotry' name should be reserved for true factories, what should I call my interface and class?

The obvious answer is IFooProvider, but I really want avoid 'XxxProvider' because it's overused and therefore too vague. On the other hand, IFooServiceLocator is far too specific.

Alternative naming suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well what do you expect from a CarFactory? Right. They produce the beer I'm having right now.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it should be a "Factory" if it doesn't always create a new instance since that's what the name implies.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer Provider over Factory if instances may be reused, but I reckon this is subjective. The important point is to use the terms consistently within your code base.

Comment: I sometimes like to use a thesaurus when I'm deciding on class names.  Looking up "factory" and "provide" give a few interesting options:  repository, store, producer, server, preparer, supplier, distributor.  I agree with Brian; the important thing is to be consistent.  You probably don't want to confuse other developers (and yourself) with strange names, but sometimes a thesaurus is handy when you just can't quite think of an appropriate name.

Comment: I like supplier a lot, actually. Although it doesn't seem all that different from provider.

Comment: The definitions of both words seem almost the same, though "supply" seems to have the additional connotation that something is being supplied because it is lacking or required.

Comment: I'm still confused, what is supposed to be the relation between IFooFactory and IFilterFactory ?

Comment: @nos Argh! Sorry, my mistake. All references to 'Filter' should have been 'Foo'. I'm leaking specifics of my real application there. I've modified the example now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you call something a cookie factory if it sometimes made cake?

Comment: Depends upon [whether VAT is chargeable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaffa_cakes#Cake_or_biscuit.3F).

Comment: Or better: Would you call some place a cookie factory if you showed up and they only had a few cookies and they were like, "Share, everybody!"

Comment: @Dan, I think I'd be suspicious and call it a mafia front.

Answer (score 3):

Your class *provides* an `IFilter`, which may or may not entail creating one. I fail to see how `FilterProvider` is too vague.

If you don't like it, what about `FilterSource`?

Honestly, though, I don't think it'd be so bad to call it `FilterFactory`; I mean, who cares that much how it's implemented? If someone calls your `Create` method, chances are they're caching the result, which makes it pretty moot whether or not they know that `Create` doesn't *actually* instantiate a new object from scratch.

Either way, the right thing to do is document your class's actual functionality, including whatever details will be relevant to those utilizing it (and omitting those details which are, in fact, irrelevant or unimportant).

Comment: I'm not sure that documenting the concrete class would help as consumers will be using the interface for accessing the factory. Therefore, they must rely on the contract implied by the name and not documentation of the concrete class. I concede though, that IFilterProvider may be acceptable, and that my objection to it is purely subjective.

Comment: @Damian: Picky picky! You're right; I should have said "type's" rather than "class's"; my point was that you should document whatever needs to be documented. In the case of `IFilterFactory`, for example, regardless whether or not others interpret the -`Factory` part to mean that an implementation creates a new instance, you could put into the documentation: "An `IFilterFactory` provides an instance of an `IFilter` implementation via the `Create` method. This is not guaranteed to create a new object." But then with that definition it really seems like `IFilterProvider` might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

So far, it seems to be 50/50. So the answer I'm accepting is the one that implies 'Yes; it *is* wrong to name something as a FooFactory if it doesn't *always* create new Foo objects' because that's where my own preference lies.

Comment: I feel you made a wise decision there